# Areas of tetrahedron faces in proportion to opposite solid angles?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, solid-angle

Is there a relationship analogous to the law of sines for triangles, but for tetrahedra? A natural generalization would be 
$$
a : b : c : d \;=\; \sin A : \sin B : \sin C : \sin D
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are face areas, and $A,B,C,D$ are opposite
solid angles.
If the above does not hold, does some other similar relationship hold connecting $\{a,b,c,d\}$ to $\{A,B,C,D\}$?

Comment: Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Higher_dimensions

Comment: @Vasya: Thank you! I was ignorant of the polar sine.